# Sitecore 9.1 Azure master index rebuild gets stuck

Tags: indexing, sitecore, azure-cognitive-search, paas

I'm working on a Sitecore PaaS solution on Azure. I provision a Sitecore xsmall instance with the standard marketplace procedure. Right after installing I went for a complete index rebuild. But when Sitecore starts rebuilding master database indexes, it gets stuck after a random number of indexes are added.

[image]

I tried a number of different configuration modifications but none of them worked.

Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

Ok, I found the logs.

Nested Exception

> Exception:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>   Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid.
>   Details: definition : Invalid index: The index contains 1036 field(s).
>   An index can have at most 1000 fields.\r\n"}}

I saw there's a patch for Sitecore 8 but I'm using v9. Can I install it anyways?

Comment: 3 views but -6 votes how it's possible?

Comment: And I don't understand why negative votes. I've search a lot before posting. And NONE of the solutions worked.

Comment: I've provisioned another instance. Same thing is happening. All indexes but master build correctly.

Comment: How is it possible that this fails in a NEW Sitecore instance with no content??

Comment: I'm from the Azure Search team at Microsoft. We don't provide support for Sitecore, but I can confirm that the error message you see is from Azure Search, and it means exactly what it says -- the index has more fields than is currently allowed. You mentioned a patch for Sitecore to fix this issue in your edited answer -- Did that help?

Comment: That patch is for Sitecore 8. I'm using Sitecore 9, I don't think I can use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting help from Sitecore, this was recognized as a bug. Reference number 207507.

As a workaround I had to manually exclude fields from being indexed:

1. in `App_Config/Include/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` set `<indexAllFields>` to `false`
2. Add fields to exclude to `App_Config/Include/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Master.ExcludeFields.config`